# Trying to separate numbers by commas in counter

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to output the final numeric value but formatted in the form of currency to show the currency symbol and commas. I tried integrating a conversion function that I found on here but having some trouble including it in the entire code. I'm quite new to this so please let me know where I went wrong in your comments and what's the best direction to go in.

This is the code for the counter:

```js
function numberWithCommas(x) {
  var parts = x.toString().split(".");
  parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  return parts.join(".");
}

var a = 0;
$(window).scroll(function () {

  var oTop = $('#counter').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
  if (a == 0 && $(window).scrollTop() > oTop) {
    $('.counter-value').each(function () {
      var $this = $(this),
        countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
      $({
        countNum: numberWithCommas.call($this.text())
      }).animate({
        countNum: countTo
      }, {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function () {
          $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
        },
        complete: function () {
          $this.text(this.countNum);
        }
      });
    });
    a = 1;
  }

});
```

```css
.counter-value {
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 17px 0;
}

.counter-value:after {
  content: attr(data-desc);
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter">
  <div class="sqs-col sqs-col-4 counter-value" data-count="2500" data-desc="Happy Clients">0</div>
  <div class="sqs-col sqs-col-4 counter-value" data-count="1000" data-desc="Projects Completed">0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: please provide us some input and output examples to give you an appropriate answer

Comment: I just read there is something called Intl.NumberFormat to change number format.

Answer (score 0):

as Kawaljit Singh suggest, or simply use toLocaleString()

```js
const nForm    = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-EN')
  ,   nFormUSD = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-EN',{style: "currency", currency: "USD"})
  ,   nFormFix2 = v => nForm.format(v.toFixed(2))
  ;

let ValueX = 1234567.123456;

console.log('Intl.NumberFormat =>', nForm.format(ValueX))

console.log('Intl.NumberFormat USD =>', nFormUSD.format(ValueX))

console.log('Intl.NumberFormat in nFormFix2', nFormFix2(ValueX))

console.log( "x.toLocaleString('en-EN')", ValueX.toLocaleString('en-EN'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**doc :**

Country Currency Codes :
 -> https://www.iban.com/currency-codes

Intl.NumberFormat.prototype.format() :
-> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat/format

Number.prototype.toLocaleString() :
-> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString